# Why there's no SELECT DISTINCT in ksqDB

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I'm trying to figure out why there's no `SELECT DISTINCT` syntax in `ksqlDB`. Is the absence caused by a conceptual factor? Or is it just missing for now?

The reason I'm asking is because I want to have a table based on an existing stream. The only way to do so is to add `GROUP BY` and aggregate function to `AS SELECT FROM`.
However, I'm not interested in any sort of aggregation. I do understand that at the moment grouping when creating a materialized table is mandatory because it precludes creating a table without a `PRIMARY KEY`, which can be inferred from `GROUP BY`.
But it also necessitates using aggregation functions(unlike regular `SQL`, `ksqlDB` doesn't allow `GROUP BY` without aggregation).
As a result, I have to create some dummy aggregation that I don't really need just to switch from a stream to a table.